# Concatenate mapping with zt mapping

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-coc

I'm using CoC and coc-python, and there is the `gd` mapping, which goes to the definition of a symbol. The mapping is defined as:

```
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(doc-definition)
```

Now, I want to first do a `vsplit` of the current buffer, then use the `gd`, and then use the `zt` mapping.

I'm using the:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>gd :vsplit<cr><Plug>(coc-definition)<cr>zt
```

but the `zt` is never executed.

I have tried using:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>gd :vsplit<cr><Plug>(coc-definition)zt
```

(i.w. removing the `<cr>` after the `(coc-definition)`) but it still does not work.

Also, there is already the definition:

```
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
```

and I just want to add the variation with the `<leader>`.

Where is my error here and how will it work?

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is that CoC is using an asynchronous action that doesn't take affect right at the point where the mapping is executed.

Looking at the CoC sources, I see there's a `CocAction()` counterpart to `CocActionAsync()`, so maybe you can use that to run the `gd` action synchronously.

Try the following:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gd :vsplit<CR>:call CocAction('jumpDefinition')<CR>zt
```

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
nmap <silent> <leader>gd :vsplit<cr><Plug>(coc-definition)zt
```

?

You start in normal mode, with `:vsplit<cr>` you start and end command-line mode. Then just just continue with `<Plug>(coc-definition)` and `zt` as normal mode mappings, no need for additional `<cr>`.

`<Plug>Something` or `<Plug>(Something)` is a special mapping for plugin authors to provide convenient way of remapping without introducing default maps that might clash with what users have.

Comment: Indeed, and the parentheses are to avoid having `<Plug>Somethingzt`, which would not work (vim would see the `zt` as part of `Something`). It's the same idea in `:help using-<Plug>`, except there they use `<Plug>Something;`

Comment: Still doesn’t work. I have tried what you are mentioning, I have also tried to use `normal zt` (with and without ! and <cr>), but still they don’t work.

Comment: It should work and it probably "works". The issue might be the coc-definition is async, thus `zt` is possibly run before definition was found.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is already a mapping of `nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)`

Comment: Also, the solution that you proposed is not working. Might be that the coc-definition is async (as you say). If this is the case, then what would it take to make it work?